# Ubuntu 20.04 shutdown slow

Tags: shutdown, 20.04, restart

I shut down (or reboot) my laptop once a week. It takes around 1-2 minutes to turn off the system.

However, previously I was on Ubuntu 16.04 and was able to see logs by pressing `Esc` key. In this version, I can only see a blinking underscore `_`. Not an option to see logs.